# how to jitter/dodge geom_segments so they remain parallel?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I did something like this with my data, but despite the transparency the segments are hard to visualise (my data has lot less number of segments than the example below) to see their beginning and end.

```
require(ggplot2)
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Petal.Length, xend = Petal.Width,
                 y = factor(Species), yend = factor(Species),
                 size = Sepal.Length)) +
    geom_segment(alpha = 0.05) + 
    geom_point(aes(shape = Species))
```

Came across [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ggplot2/Vmuya_s9pCs) solution, but the lines are criss-crossed. Is there a way to make the jitter produce parallell lines with the points at the tips? I have tried `position_dodge` instead of `position_jitter`, but it requires `ymax`. Can `ymax` be integrated at all for use with `geom_segment`?

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Petal.Length, xend = Petal.Width,
                 y = factor(Species), yend = factor(Species))) +
    geom_segment(position = position_jitter(height = 0.25))+
    geom_point(aes(size = Sepal.Length, shape = Species))
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

As far as I know, `geom_segment` does not allow jittering nor dodging. You can add jittering to the relevant variable in the data frame, then plot the jittered variable. In your example, the factor is converted to numeric, then the labels for the levels of the factor are added to the axis using `scale_y_continuous`.

```
library(ggplot2)
iris$JitterSpecies <- ave(as.numeric(iris$Species), iris$Species, 
   FUN = function(x) x + rnorm(length(x), sd = .1))

ggplot(iris, aes(x = Petal.Length, xend = Petal.Width,
                 y = JitterSpecies, yend = JitterSpecies)) +
    geom_segment()+
    geom_point(aes(size=Sepal.Length, shape=Species)) +
    scale_y_continuous("Species", breaks = c(1,2,3), labels = levels(iris$Species))
```

[image]

But it seems `geom_linerange` allows dodging.

```
ggplot(iris, aes(y = Petal.Length, ymin = Petal.Width,
                 x = Species, ymax = Petal.Length, group = row.names(iris))) +
       geom_point(position = position_dodge(.5)) +
     geom_linerange(position = position_dodge(.5)) +
     coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: Many thx! Both images are like the one I wanted. Will try it out.

Comment: Your first solution worked for me. With my data, the length of the segments represent time durations and when I use geom_linerange with facetting(scales='free'), the axis still show the whole range for the y-axis and just the range for each panel - probably because of the ymin and ymax settings. So, went in for the geom_segment. :)

Comment: @Sandy Muspratt Do you know of any documentation for the dodging behaviour of `geom_segment` ("As far as I know, `geom_segment` does not allow jittering nor dodging")? I have seen [**this post**](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/ggplot2/geom_segment$20position_dodge/ggplot2/iWojkpMicRY/ZMR75OOpHBQJ) on _vertical_ dodging, but I have a similar problem for horizontal dodging: `y` is dodged, but `yend` is not. It's slightly puzzling that `geom_segment` has a `position` argument if it's not working anyway...

Comment: Almost a decade later, see my updated answer for `ggplot2 3.4.2`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/76076569/4205652

Comment: The geom_linerange solution works great!

Answer (score 2):

Updated for `ggplot2` version 3.4.2 and to build upon another [short answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74459227/4205652):

You may now use `position = position_dodge2(width = 0.1)`.
For example:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Species,
                 ymin = Petal.Length,
                 ymax = Petal.Width)) +
  geom_linerange(position = position_dodge2(width = 0.5)) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_bw()
```

Will produce this figure:[image: Example ggplot2 output.]

Note that `ggplot2` only allows `geom_linerange()` for the y-axis, hence the use of `coord_flip()`.

Answer (score 1):

The `position` argument of `geom_segment` might be helpful for you, see [Slightly change geom_segment's position of x only, but keep position of xend constant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70210095/slightly-change-geom-segments-position-of-x-only-but-keep-position-of-xend-con)