# Grouped data by factor with geom_segment

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to show clusters of segments by factor groups using `geom_segment` but the `position` parameter doesn't seem to be doing anything. Here's an example:

```
mydata = data.frame(variable = factor(c("A","A","A","B","C")),
                    color = factor(c(1,2,3,4,5)),
                    start = c(1,2,1,4,6),
                    end = c(3,4,6,5,8))

ggplot(mydata, aes(x = start, xend = end, y = variable, yend = variable)) + 
  geom_segment(aes(color = color, position = "stack"), size = 3)
```

[image]

I've also tried `position = "dodge"`. Group A should have 3 segments, but they're all covered up by the green bar. Adjusting the transparency will be too confusing visually. How can I make sure that all the segments for each factor show up side-by-side?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21904364/324364) is probably a duplicate. I can give a specific example if you need more direction than that question provides...

Comment: Also, you need to set position outside of `aes` with something like `position = position_dodge(.2)`.

Comment: @joran Thanks for pointing to that one. Not sure why that didn't show up in my searches. I'll take a look at it to decide if that one speaks to the kind of solution I/others would realistically use.

Comment: Specifically, you'll want to do the `geom_linerange` option with `coord_flip`.

Comment: @alistaire the ```position_dodge``` moves the segments along the x axis, not the y.

Comment: Yup, so you've got to `+ coord_flip()`

Comment: @alistaire I meant that the position_dodge slide along the x when still using geom_segment. Got it though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm a little uncertain that @alistaire and I are communicating this clearly to you, so here's what we mean:

```
mydata = data.frame(variable = factor(c("A","A","A","B","C")),
                                        color = factor(c(1,2,3,4,5)),
                                        start = c(1,2,1,4,6),
                                        end = c(3,4,6,5,8))

ggplot(mydata, aes(ymin = start, ymax = end, x = variable)) + 
    geom_linerange(aes(color = color),position = position_dodge(width = 0.2), size = 3) + 
    coord_flip()
```

Which results in:

[image]

Comment: Yes, you communicated clearly. I was still working on it. Thank you!

Comment: Out of curiosity and to help contextualize this answer for future miffed users: Do you know the intended difference/usage between geom_segment and geom_linerange?

Comment: @Nancy You can think of `geom_linerange` as a convenient version of `geom_segment` for a specific use case. `geom_segment` is for when you need to draw arbitrary line segments in a fairly non-systematic way. `geom_linerange` is for the specific case of a collection of vertical bars at specified x values with different lengths (e.g. error bars, etc).