# Dodge Effect with geom_segment

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-segment

I have the following dataset where I am visualizing a range comparison for different features between two model types in `ggplot2` with `geom_segment`.

```
test <- data.frame("var" = c("apple", "apple", "banana", "banana", "pear", "pear"),
                   "model" = c("mod1", "mod2", "mod1", "mod2", "mod1", "mod2"),
                   "lower" = c(1, 3, 2, 5, 6, 2),
                   "upper" = c(7, 5, 7, 7, 10, 6))
```

Below is the code snippet I am currently using for the visual, as well as the output. But right now the two different `model` types are overlayed on the plot, and **I would like to have them "dodged" so that they are next to each other instead of overlayed**. Any ideas?

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(test) + 
  geom_segment(aes(x=var, 
                   xend=var, 
                   y=lower, 
                   yend=upper, 
                   colour=model, 
                   group=model), size=8) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Does this other answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/21922792/6851825

Comment: @JonSpring it does. thank you. i'll add my answer based on that post.