# Apply position_dodge to geom_segment

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have been trying to plot a slightly modified bar chart, where I manually input the start and end values of each bar and they are represented by arrows. The problem is that with geom_segment the arrows overlap. I just need them to be grouped by country and each arrow besides the other (5 arrows per country, specified in a category column in the df), with a wider gap between countries.

Here is the data set

```
structure(list(country = c("Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", 
"Europe", "China", "China", "China", "China", "China", "India", 
"India", "India", "India", "India", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", 
"Brazil", "Brazil", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA"), category = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), y = c(0L, 899620L, 783001L, 
1073611L, 875287L, 0L, 2397951L, 3529763L, 4178099L, 4352804L, 
0L, 1290543L, 1316816L, 1377391L, 1272729L, 0L, 963706L, 961357L, 
544286L, 276219L, 0L, 1051162L, 441454L, 262085L, 348517L), yend = c(899620L, 
783001L, 1073611L, 875287L, 1442741L, 2397951L, 3529763L, 4178099L, 
4352804L, 2564677L, 1290543L, 1316816L, 1377391L, 1272729L, 923000L, 
963706L, 961357L, 544286L, 276219L, 249263L, 1051162L, 441454L, 
262085L, 348517L, 1314709L)), row.names = c(NA, -25L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```

What I have tried:

```
  ggplot(
    aes(
      x = country, xend = country, 
      y = y, yend = yend,
      ),
    position = position_dodge(width = 0.2)) +
  geom_segment(
    arrow = arrow(angle = 30, length = unit(0.2, 'cm')),
    linewidth = 1
  )
```

It looks something like this
[image]

I also tried doing it with geom_arrowsegment, as it should allow to adjust the position, but they start all over the place and I cannot just put them parallel to the other arrows. I also tried it with `position_dodge2` but it did not change anything

```
ggplot(consumption_supplychain) +
  geom_arrowsegment(aes(x = country, xend = country, y = y, yend = yend),
                    position = position_jitter())
```

Here, it looks terrible:
[image]

Comment: This looks like a very similar question, does it resolve your issue? https://stackoverflow.com/a/21922792/6851825

Comment: I looked at that solution earlier and they suggest using `geom_linerange()` instead of `geom_segment()`, the problem with this is that I really need the arrows and that is not possible with linerange. That is why I tried with `geom_arrowsegment` but it is also not looking good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to stick to segments, but use numeric values:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(xval = as.numeric(factor(country)) + (category - 3) / 8) %>%
  ggplot(aes(xval, y)) +
  geom_segment(aes(xend = xval, yend = yend, color = yend > y), 
               arrow = arrow(angle = 30, length = unit(2, "mm"))) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("red2", "green4"), guide = "none") +
  scale_x_continuous("Country", breaks = 1:5, 
                     labels = levels(factor(df$country))) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16)
```

[image]

Which also works nicely if you ditch the arrows and use color to indicate direction:

```r
df %>%
  mutate(xval = as.numeric(factor(country)) + (category - 3) / 8) %>%
  ggplot(aes(xval, y)) +
  geom_segment(aes(xend = xval, yend = yend, color = yend > y), 
               linewidth = 7) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("red2", "green4"), guide = "none") +
  scale_x_continuous("Country", breaks = 1:5, 
                     labels = levels(factor(df$country))) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16)
```

[image]

Comment: They all look great! Thanks a lot. So what you do here `mutate(xval = as.numeric(factor(country)) + (category - 3) / 8) ` is to convert the countries into numeric values to be able to adjust their position? Why cannot we just use `category` as it is if it is already numeric?

Comment: @Raksha we _are_ using `category`, it's just that the numeric values of country will be 1:5, and we use category to dodge them by a small fraction on either side

Comment: Are you already specifying that with `-3/8` or first with `scale_x_continuous`?. Sorry, I am not connecting the dots on what is happening with the mutate line and if that is the start of the dodging part. Thanks again!

Comment: Since `category` is made of the numbers [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], the expression `(category - 3)/8` results in these values being converted to [-0.25, -0.125, 0,  0.125, 0.25.]. When we add these to the value 1 (for Brazil) we get [0.75, 0.875, 1, 1.125, 1.25]. When we add them to 2 for China we get [1.75, 1.875, 2, 2.125, 2.25] and so on for the other countries. These are the x axis locations of the segments @Raksha

Comment: Just a side note, instead of `(category - 3)/8` you can use```scales::rescale(category, to=c(-0.25, 0.25))```.

Comment: I have a follow up question. I added another column to the df specifying one color for each category (so a total of five colors). If I put `colour=consumption_supplychain$col` inside `aes`, I can specify a legend with `scale_color_manual` but the color of the arrows do not match the color of the category. It does takes the 5 colors I used, but in the wrong order. If I use `colour=consumption_supplychain$col` outside `aes`, it starts using the right colors but then I am not able to get a legend. Do you have an idea what the problem could be?

Comment: @AllanCameron  I am still having the same problem with the colors of the plot, (see my past comment) so I am happy for any help regarding this problem! I was also wondering if it is possible to nudge the countries a little bit, so that the space between them is not as big.

Answer (score 3):

`geom_segment` does not support `position`. You can use `geom_line` instead.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

consumption_supplychain %>% 
  mutate(grp = paste(country, category)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(c(y, yend), names_to = "Start_End", values_to = "y") %>% 
 ggplot(., aes(x = country , y = y, group = grp)) +
  geom_line(arrow = arrow(length=unit(0.30,"cm"), 
                          ends="last", type = "closed"), 
             position = position_dodge(0.5))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-09-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

What about switching to facets?

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(consumption_supplychain,
  aes(x = category, xend = category, y = y, yend = yend))+
  geom_segment(arrow = arrow(angle = 30, length = unit(0.2, 'cm')), 
               linewidth = 1) +
  labs(x = "Country") +
  facet_grid(cols = vars(country), switch = "x") +
  theme(strip.placement = "outside", 
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(), 
        axis.text.x = element_blank())
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-09-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Input data:

```r
consumption_supplychain <- structure(list(country = c("Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", 
"Europe", "China", "China", "China", "China", "China", "India", 
"India", "India", "India", "India", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", 
"Brazil", "Brazil", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA"), category = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), y = c(0L, 899620L, 783001L, 
1073611L, 875287L, 0L, 2397951L, 3529763L, 4178099L, 4352804L, 
0L, 1290543L, 1316816L, 1377391L, 1272729L, 0L, 963706L, 961357L, 
544286L, 276219L, 0L, 1051162L, 441454L, 262085L, 348517L), yend = c(899620L, 
783001L, 1073611L, 875287L, 1442741L, 2397951L, 3529763L, 4178099L, 
4352804L, 2564677L, 1290543L, 1316816L, 1377391L, 1272729L, 923000L, 
963706L, 961357L, 544286L, 276219L, 249263L, 1051162L, 441454L, 
262085L, 348517L, 1314709L)), row.names = c(NA, -25L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I'd have added  `xlab("country")` to your code to show the "right" axis title. Cheers.